# Invoke Postgres query with multiple columns inside IN clause using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a following, simplified, Postgre SQL database 'construction' table:

| id | model | status | not_relevant_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TO_BE_DECIDED | ABANDONED | some data |
| 2 | TO_BE_DECIDED | COMPLETE | some data |
| 3 | OLD_MODEL | ABANDONED | some data |
| 4 | OLD_MODEL | COMPLETE | some data |

In Postgres I can select columns in following way:

```
    select c.id from construction c
    where (c.model, c.status) in (
        ('TO_BE_DECIDED', 'ABANDONED'),
        ('OLD_MODEL', 'COMPLETE') )
```

and I get following rows returned:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |

How can I call query like this using Spring JPA (non-native or native query), where I can pass IN conditions as a List?
Additional requirements:

1. I'd like not to use tricks like concatenations into single value, so that DB indexes are still used.
2. There can be more than 2 columns used, e.g. 5,  inside IN clause.

I tried with passing List<ConstructionFilter> in @Query statement, but I get QuerySyntaxException instead of a List containing values 1 and 4:

```
    @Query("select c.id " +
        "from Construction c " +
        "where (c.model, c.status) in (:filter.model, :filter.status)"
    )
    List<Long> getConstructions(@Param("filter") List<ConstructionFilter> filter);
```

where

```
    @Builder
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class ConstructionFilter {
        private String model;
        private String status;
    }
```

Comment: Such syntax could only possibly be supported via a native query.  JPA uses HQL (Hibernate Query Language) under the hood, which does not AFAIK support the tuple syntax.

Comment: Please additionally consider the fact that I'm not talking only about a tuple, as more columns should be supported.
Given that, are you able @TimBiegeleisen to provide native query where I can pass a List<ConstructionFilter> as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

If you were retrieving entities I would say the solution is:

```
public interface Construction Repository extends CrudRepository<Construction, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Construction> {

    default List<Construction> getConstructions(List<ConstructionFilter> filter) {
        Specification<Construction> specification = (root, cq, cb) -> cb.or(
                filter.stream().map(f -> cb.and(
                        cb.equal(root.get("model"), f.getModel()),
                        cb.equal(root.get("status"), f.getModel())
                )).toArray(Predicate[]::new)
        );
        return findAll(specification);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, that does not allow to retrieve ids only, implementing [custom](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-base-repository/) or [fragment](https://thorben-janssen.com/composite-repositories-spring-data-jpa/) repository might help.